# How do I run another program from a C++ program

Tags: c++, function, shell, terminal, system

I am trying to call on another program to perform a function (I have no idea what, only that it is not written in C++, but in shell) on a file within my C++ program. I do not know how to actually perform the function within my program. I do know that I write something like this

```
system(PROGRAM HERE);
```

The problem is that I do not know exactly how I am supposed to type the program out. I believe that if the function were to be called dostuff, I would type out

```
system("dostuff");
```

... I think. But what if there are arguments attached to that function that I would give as variables within my C++ program? That is what I would really need help with. In the terminal, I would type in "`dostuff -1 arg"`. So in C++ would I type out

```
int arg = 5;

system("dostuff" arg);
```

Comment: ked, Welcome to SO. It is hard to understand what is being asked here. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could format the string first. With `<sstream>` included:

```
int arg = 5;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "dostuff " << arg;
system(ss.str().c_str());
```

Alternatively, you could use the concatenation feature of `std::string`. If you prefer the C-style formatters, you could use `snprintf` to similar effect.

Comment: thanks! it worked! doing it the way I had it wasnt working so... you saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is

```
system("dostuff -1 5");
```

Essentially you need to construct the terminal argument and pass that to the system call.

Ex:

```
int arg = 5;
std::stringstream command;

command << "dostuff -1 " << arg;

system(command.str());
```